# Нужна ли запятая перед «если» в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

*Поэтому если оформите свой даже за 10 минут до закрытия, то все равно его принесём.*

Comment: Я так понимаю, здесь пропущено слово "заказ"?

Answer (score 2):

***Нет, запятая не нужна,*** потому что во второй части есть частица *то.*

[Вот](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=286467) ответ Грамоты на подобный вопрос (правда, она ничего не объясняет):

**Вопрос № 286467**

Нужна ли запятая перед если в следующем предложении: Поэтому если решитесь на покупку, то кому-то нужно будет затравить пару часов на поиск приемлемой цены.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

Запятая перед *если* в этом предложении не нужна.